# Is there an easy way to find out which of two frames is closer to the root in a Multibody plant?

Tags: collision, robotics, drake, motion-planning

I am working on recovering from collision. I have the names of bodies in collision and the frames associated with them and now I want to move the body/frame that is closer to the end effector to get out of collision, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to get this information from a `MultiBodyPlant`. I could construct another representation of the graph and search through it, but I was wondering if it is possible to maybe get this from `drake` instead?

The problem is that sometimes the robot ends up in collision with itself or the environment and I want to make a plan to recover it.
From the `QueryObject`, I am able to get a `vector<SignedDistancePair>` that gives me the geometry IDs of object instances collision, and unit vector pointing in the direction of fastest increase in collision depth
Then I use a `SceneGraphInspector` to get the corresponding frame IDs and then use the frame IDs to get the bodies in collision
For now I make the assumption that only two bodies are in collision
Now that I have the two bodies in collision, I want to find the one that is closer to the end effector and is therefore easier to move out of collision

Comment: Workflow question: Why are you doing this via indexing rather than using distances and gradients? (is it b/c distances / gradients are ill-conditioned when trying to recover from "in-collision"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow.  I think you're right that we don't make this one easy (but we should).

For now, I would think you can call `MultibodyPlant::GetJointIndices()` and then loop the joints via `MultibodyPlant::get_joint()` to find the joint `Joint::child_body() == collision_body`, and then use `Joint::parent_body()`.  And we can open an issue if avoiding that (small?) linear search becomes important?

Comment: Thank you, @Russ! I had `GetJointIndices` and was trying to find a way to get a `Joint` from the index but I didn't try searching in snake case. In general, is there a convention `drake` follows as to what kind of function names are typically in snake case? (I'll make this a separate question if you think it should be)

Comment: the lower case is for very cheap functions... O(1) and less that 5 lines long
https://drake.mit.edu/styleguide/cppguide.html#Function_Names